# How to define these hash functions in python3?

Tags: python, hash, sha256

I am trying to define this hash function in python3 using SHA256 but I don't understand how I should do it :

h:{0,1}^* X {0,1}^* X G--> (Z_q)^*
where G is an additive group with order q.
I tried this but I don't think it's the right way to do it :

```
def h(string1, string2, g:int):
  h = hashlib.sha256()
  h.update(b'string1')
  h.update(b'string2')
  h.update(b'g')
  res = h.digest()
  return (res)
```

For example the hash function takes this as input:
S = h(pid1||pid2||Y||P)
where pid1 and pid2 are binary strings and Y and P are two points from the additive group G.
[This](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/12/10/1687/htm) is the article that contain this hash function maybe it can help.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered in its current form. You have provided the domain and codomain of the hash function you want to implement: `h` should take as input two binary strings and an element of a group `G`. The output should be some string in `Z_q^*`. However, your question does not specify how this string should be constructed. So it is impossible for us to tell whether your Python function satisfies the formal specification. Please extend your question with the necessary information.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to add more details and thank you for your advice

Comment: You're on the right track. You only have to figure out 1. how the element of `G` can be serialized to bytes for it to be hashed as well as 2. how you can transform the result into an element of `Z_q^*`. I don't know what kind of group `Z_q^*`` is supposed to be. Perhaps it is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) one.

Comment: @ArtjomB Yes Zq^* is a multiplicative group of integers, do you have any idea on how to transform the result into an element of the Zq^* ?

Comment: Ok the paper you linked is very helpful for understanding your question (though the paper is a bit imprecise at some parts). So basically `G` is supposed to be the additive group defined by an elliptic curve. So it would probably be a good starting point to use an ECC library, such as [ECPY](http://cslashm.github.io/ECPy/). ECPy might also provide helper functions for encoding the group elements.

Comment: For example one weird part of the paper is that in table 1 it talks about two points `P` and `Q` on the curve, with `P = aQ`, but it also says that `aQ` is in `Z_q*`. I guess what they mean is that `a` is in `Z_q*`. Also in the same table they say "Given two points ..." and then "It is hard to calculate the points". I think what they meant is that it is hard to calculate the coefficients. This seems a bit sloppy (and makes me wonder how trustworthy the definition of the hash functions is).

Comment: Actually I agree with you